# Mount network drive permanently

Tags: linux, ubuntu, osmc, fstab

it's probably a nooby question, but I got some problems with mounting my Samba Share to my Raspberry Pi with OSMC on it.

My Samba Server got the IP: 192.168.178.41
Credentials for the Share:
User: nas
Password: randompassword

I watched many tutorials, but it still won't work.

If I type in the console "sudo mount -t cifs -o username=nas //192.168.178.41/hdd2/Downloads /usr/HDD2Downloads/" it works.

But if I edit the /etc/fstab file it doesn't work.

[image: My /etc/fstab file looks like that]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't know why but it cuts my "Hello guys" out of the text. Sorry for that.